# How do I create variables within Heredoc Terraform to be used inside a for block

Tags: terraform, heredoc

```
<<EOT
    %{ for ip in aws_instance.example.*.private_ip ~}
    %{ part0 = split(".", ${ip})[0] }
    server ${part0}
    %{ endfor ~}
EOT
```

Is there a way to get a variable assigned in the for block which can be used for later before the block completes

adding

```
%{ part0 = split(".", ${ip})[0] }
```

within for block shows "invalid template control keyword"

Comment: You don't need a `${}` inside a `%{}` block. Try: `%{ part0 = split(".", ip)[0] }`

Comment: Thanks Mark. Unfortunately that does not work. %{ part0 = split(".", ip)[0] ~} shows part0 is not a valid template control keyword

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to define a variable (`part0`) inside the template. I don't think you can define variables like that in a heredoc template. You're also trying to add an extra string interpolation (`${}`) inside the `split()` call, where string interpolation should not be used.

Please try this:

```
<<EOT
    %{ for ip in aws_instance.example.*.private_ip ~}
    server ${split(".", ip)[0]}
    %{ endfor ~}
EOT
```